# Haskell monad into monad

Tags: haskell, monads

There are method `(>>=) :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.
How can i make method `:: forall a b. m (n a) -> (a -> m (n b)) -> m (n b)` where m and n is monads.

Comment: `(>>=) :: Monad (m n) => m n a -> (a -> m n b) -> m n b` is valid (`m` cannot be a Monad here because it has the wrong kind).

Comment: I have: `type TargetClient = ReaderT TargetClientChannels IO` and `type MethodResult a = Either ResponseError a`. I also have functions `a -> TargetClient (MethodResult a)`. How can I connect them?

Comment: Why not write a question describing this actual problem in detail? As it stands, I fail to see what you mean by "connect them" (connect how? what are the desired semantics? etc.)

Comment: Perhaps monad transformers are what you're looking for?  ([Here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html) and [here](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#monad-transformers)).

Comment: Result of function `a -> TargetClient (MethodResult a)` transfer to the next  `a -> TargetClient (MethodResult a)` whithout do notation and `case of`s

Comment: @Chris: May be, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Did you mean `(>>=) :: m (n a) -> (a -> m (n b)) -> m (n b)`?

Comment: @PyRulez: Yes, apparently I did not write the correct.

Comment: @Max There is no general solution for arbitrary `m` and `n`, but for specific `m` and `n` there might be a solution. It also depends on what you want `>>=` to do, since otherwise `a >>= f = undefined` works fine.

Comment: @PyRulez: Do I need to create custom method for my types? It's a pity!

Comment: @Max you could combine them into one big monad.

Comment: If you could find a general solution for arbitrary m and n, wouldn't monads compose then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PyRulez writes, there's no general solution for this, but given the types you report, something like the following should work.

You're going to need

```
import Control.Monad (join)
```

Using `do` notation, you can compose two functions, `foo` and `bar`, like this:

```
comp :: (a -> TargetClient (MethodResult b)) ->
        (b -> TargetClient (MethodResult c)) ->
         a -> TargetClient (MethodResult c)
comp foo bar x = do
  f <- foo x
  b <- join <$> traverse bar f
  return b
```

If you don't like the `do` notation, you can reduce it all to this:

```
comp' :: (a -> TargetClient (MethodResult b)) ->
         (b -> TargetClient (MethodResult c)) ->
          a -> TargetClient (MethodResult c)
comp' foo bar x = foo x >>= fmap join . traverse bar
```

When you map `f` with `bar`, you'll get the monads stacked in the wrong order, so to speak, but you can use `traverse` to switch the stack. Even when you do that, you'll have an `Either` in an `Either`, so that's the reason you need `join`.

Comment: I again was inattentive. My functions have a semantics such as `a -> TargetClient (MethodResult b)`, `b -> TargetClient (MethodResult c)`, etc.

Comment: @Max That shouldn't make any difference. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If both `m` and `n` are monads, you need an additional piece to make the composite `m.n` a monad as well.

What is required is a "distributive law", that is a natural morphism 
`forall a . n(m a) -> m(n a)`  (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_law_between_monads) it comes from Beck and is also used in Street)

It then becomes easy to write the missing piece and verify it satisfies the monad laws.